# Does upgrading nexus3 container from 3.18.0 to 3.47 have any path?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sonatype, nexus3

I want to upgrade my Nexus Docker container from `sonatype/nexus3:3.18.0` to `sonatype/nexus3:3.47.1`

My docker-compose is

```
nexus:
    image: sonatype/nexus3:3.18.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      NEXUS_CONTEXT: nexus
      INSTALL4J_ADD_VM_PARAMS: "-Xms4703m -Xmx4703m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=4703m -Djava.util.prefs.userRoot=/nexus-data/javaprefs"
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
      - 8083:8083
      - 8084:8084
      - 8085:8085
    volumes:
      - ${DOCKER_VOLUME_BASE:?base}/Nexus/data:/nexus-data
    networks:
      default:
```

Do I need upgrade step by step? Like GitLab Docker container? or just change `docker-compose` to new version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just change docker-compose to new version.

Before that, please read [Upgrading a Standalone Instance](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/installation-and-upgrades/upgrading-a-standalone-instance)